# Windowsがロック画面の状態で、デスクトップアプリにSendMessageを送りたい

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

Windowsのロック画面中に、USB接続のリモコン操作をトリガーに、
デスクトップアプリの該当のボタンに「マウスクリック」のSendMessageを送信したい
と考えています。

```
※マウスクリック時の処理を直接呼出しが出来れば簡単ですが、
  外部アプリケーションでAPIがないため、
  マウス操作をプログラムで実施して、処理を呼び出す方法を考えています。
```

下記に、マウスクリック部のソースを抜粋しますが、
ロック画面でなければ実現できているため、
ロック画面中だと、デスクトップにマウス操作は通知できないのかと思います。

実現方法をご存じの方はいないでしょうか。

---- ソース抜粋 開始 -----

～ USBリモコンのボタンイベントのハンドル部 ～

//マウス左クリックダウン
SendMessage(クリック対象のボタンハンドル, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON, 0x000A000A);
//マウス左クリックアップ 
SendMessage(クリック対象のボタンハンドル, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0x00000000, 0x000A000A);

～ USBリモコンのボタンイベントのハンドル部 ～

----- ソース抜粋 終了 -----

Answer (score 3):

結論としてはできませんし、やるべきではありません。

Windowsにはユーザー切り替えの機能がありますが、切り替わっている間、元のユーザーのデスクトップは操作を受け付けていません。
ロック画面やUACダイアログも同様のことが言えて、元のユーザーのデスクトップは操作を受け付けていません。このデスクトップのことをSecure Desktopと呼びます。
仮に質問の内容を実現する場合はSecure Desktopのマウス入力を取得した上で、その内容を元のデスクトップに対して`SendMessage()`することになります。しかしこれが実現できるとするとパスワードのキー入力も盗聴できることになってしまい、ウイルスそのものと言えます。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございました。

セキュリティの観点から考えて、実現は難しそうですね。
おっしゃるとおり、仮に出来たとしても、セキュリティホールを突いたウイルスだと思いますので、いつ対策されてもおかしくないと思います。

Answer (score 2):

sayuriさんが書かれているように、ユーザーが起動したアプリでロック画面の入力を受け取ったり、あるいはロック画面を操作するようなことはできません。ロック画面がというより、[デスクトップ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682573(v=vs.85).aspx)を超えてメッセージの送受信などを行うことができないようになっています。一方、ロック画面に切り替わった状態でも元のデスクトップで起動したアプリケーション同士はウィンドウメッセージの送受信ができます。

ですから、壁となっているのはメッセージ送信ではなくUSBリモコンからのイベント受信ではないのでしょうか？これをウィンドウメッセージに頼っているとロック画面で受信するのは難しいでしょうし、ソケット通信やシリアル通信であればデスクトップがアクティブでなくとも受信できます。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。

ソケット通信やシリアル通信が出来れば、よいのですが、
メッセージ送信先のアプリが対応していない（できない）ため、
難しそうです。

Comment: @M.K 誤解させてしまったようで申し訳ないのですが、ソケット通信やシリアル通信ならと書いたのはUSBリモコンのイベント受信の話です。同じデスクトップ上で起動したアプリの間では、ロック画面に切り替わっている間でもメッセージの送受信はできたので、問題はUSBリモコンからのイベント受信なのでは？と。

Comment: 同じデスクトップ上で起動したアプリの‌​間では、ロック画面に切り替わっている間で‌​もメッセージの送受信が可能とのことですが、クリックを起こすことも可能だったのでしょうか？

USBリモコンからのイベント受信は、ロック画面中でも可能でした。

Comment: @M.K WinFormsのButtonコントロールに対して別のアプリから、質問に書かれていたようなメッセージを1秒ごとに送ってみたところ、Clickイベントがきちんと1秒ごとに発生していました。ただ、確かにこのあたりの挙動はアプリの実装による可能性はあります。